# Reset the HTML table on change

Tags: javascript

I am working on expense management with pouchdb
The data is inserted into the database based on date
i want to reset to original table if there is no data in date onchange

[image]

Above picture is with data on particular date
if i change the date the table is not reset to original table

[image]

this picture is when changing the date the table is not resetting

only head row and one row is hard coded extra rows or dynamically created on click add row button

```js
//add row
function addRow(no_of_rows){
    for (let i = 0; i < no_of_rows; i++){
        console.log(i)
        var root = document.getElementById('customers').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var rows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var clone = cloneEl(rows[rows.length - 1]);
        cleanUpInputs(clone);
        root.appendChild(clone);
        
        function cloneEl(el) {
            var clo = el.cloneNode(true);
            return clo;
        }
        function cleanUpInputs(obj) {
            for (var i = 0; n = obj.childNodes[i]; ++i) {
            if (n.childNodes && n.tagName != 'INPUT') {
                cleanUpInputs(n);
            } else if (n.tagName == 'INPUT') {
                n.value = '';
            }
            }  
        }
    }   
    
}

// getting data from pouchdb 
function getAccounts(){
    var getdate = document.getElementById('Expdate').value;
    var table = document.getElementById('customers');
    db.get(getdate, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
          
          //want to handle the table reset here
          
           
        } else {
           console.log(doc);
           addRow(doc['DailyAccount'].length -1);
           for (let i = 0; i < doc['DailyAccount'].length; i++){
                // console.log(i);
                table.rows[i+1].cells[0].firstChild.value = doc.DailyAccount[i]['Description'];
                table.rows[i+1].cells[1].firstChild.value = doc.DailyAccount[i]['Investment'];
                table.rows[i+1].cells[2].firstChild.value = doc.DailyAccount[i]['Expenses'];
           }
                document.getElementById("investtotal").value = doc.TotalInvestment;
                document.getElementById("exptotal").value = doc.TotalExpenses;
        }
    });
    
  
}
```

```html
<input type="date" name="Date" id="Expdate" onchange="getAccounts()" > 
  <button onclick="addRow(1)"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add Row</button>
  <button onclick="DeleteRow()"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete Row</button>
    <table id="customers">
        <tbody id="mytbody">
            <tr>                                  
                <th>Descritption</th> 
                <th>Investment</th>
                <th>Expenses</th>                                                                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="yourname" /> </td> 
                <td onchange="getinvest()"><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>
                <td onchange="getexpense()"><input type="number" name="yourname" /></td>                                   
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <label for="fname">Investment Total : </label>
    <input type="number" name="Investtotal" id="investtotal">
    <label for="fname">Expense Total : </label>
    <input type="number" name="Exptotal" id="exptotal">
    <input type="button" id="save" value ="save" name="save" onclick="day()">
```

structure of pouchdb doc

```
var Accountdoc = {
     _id: getdate,
     TotalInvestment:Totalinvest,
     TotalExpenses: Totalexp,
     DailyAccount: Accounts,// accounts is array of object 
 };
```

Comment: Can you share the example structure of doc?

Comment: shared in question

Comment: Empty the values of the table rows before for loop. Something like: `table.rows[i+1].cells[0].firstChild.value = ""`

Comment: can you elaborate where to put the empty values in btw row varies according to daily data if we reset the values there will be many rows on different date i want to reset to original table with one head row and one empty row

Comment: Can you share the code of addRow()?

Comment: added to snippet please check

Comment: You can try checking whether there is some data or not and if not then you can call removeRow function to remove the rows. You can add a condition like `if(doc['DailyAccount'].length == 0){  ...removeRows  }`

Comment: no not working if doc is missing in particular date ochange the doc throws error  doc missing error automatically we should handle table reset on the error